# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset server-client

Tags: java, connection, client, server, socketexception

Although I have read some posts I didnt have manage to solve my issue!

I am trying to make a client server application with symmetric encryption. So here is what I do.

This is my while from my server

```
 while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        AES_Cipher.init (Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, AES_Key);


plaintext_decrypted = AES_Cipher.doFinal (inputLine.getBytes("UTF-8"));

        System.out.println("Server receive : "+ plaintext_decrypted);
        System.out.println("type message :");
        outputLine = stdIn.readLine();
        out.println(outputLine);
    }
```

Before I put this line `plaintext_decrypted = AES_Cipher.doFinal (inputLine.getBytes("UTF-8"));`

Everything works. But when I try to decrypt my message it crushes :/

Answer (score 0):

1. Read bytes, not lines. There are no lines in cipher text.
2. Move the cipher init ahead of the read loop. You don't want to re initialize it every time around the loop.
3. Don't use `doFinal(),` use `update(),` assuming the sender did the same, which is rather likely.

Comment: I use this "BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));" to read from socket. I cant read bytes with this so I guess I have to change this one. I used update() instead of doFinal() but it didnt worked still crushes :/ Anyway thank you for your help :)

Comment: This is my error: Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset 
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source) 
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source) 
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source) 
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source) 
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source) 
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source) 
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source) 
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source) 
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source) 
at Client.main(Client.java:58)